# Android Studio adding MP3 sound

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, mp3, media

I am making an app where I want to give the user an option to play background music after clicking on a little button or stop it. I used the code below but it can't find my "loop.mp3" file that I put into res/raw.

What did I do wrong and how can I change it?

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (i==1){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.loop);
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        Snackbar.make(view, "start", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        i++;
    }else {
        mp.stop();
        Snackbar.make(view, "stop", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you defined this mp3?

Comment: ou i put it outside so that is why it didnt work... thanks for help :)